# Regex matches non-matching group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to match some names within an fullname, which is the name + certain information like year of release or author.
I want to get the realName within the fullName.

```
[author1] Shuu [Digital]
[author1] Paradise ~★  Special Edition
 (magazin) [kulmov_ (Kurowa)] Channel (Fate/Grand Order) [Chinese] [*'N]
(COMIC1☆7) [ComicCon] X-Men!! (Marvel)
(magazin) [Rave (Jacky)] SPLASH 11 (Microsoft)
[anotherauthor] name1 | name2 (Hatsujou Complex) [English]
[author7 (aurhot234)] Connect (Project) [Digital]
[author3] ~Hellverse~ (COMICcon 2017)
[author4] Escape [English] [Decensored]
```

What I found is that the name is nearly always after an "]" or an ")". Then there is an whitespace and then the name. After the name is an whitespace and either nothing or "(" or "[".
The name can contain some non-ASCII ? symbols. The full name can contain japanic symbols.

I have found:

```
]\s+(.+)+\s*[\(|\[|\s]*
```

I have no idea why but it does match from the "]" util the very end of the string including the whitespaces.
But as I see it, it should only match everything after "]", grab the realName and then stop after it finds an "(" or "[".

How do I fix that?

Comment: Please show what you expect the result to be.

Comment: The `.+` will match everything to the end of the string, and the remaining parts of the pattern don't have to match anything because they have `*` quantifiers.

Comment: What is the purpose of `(.+)+`? The outer/last `+` will only ever fire once, because the inner/first `+` has already grabbed everything.

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea why but it does match from the "]" util the very end of the string including the whitespaces. But as I see it, it should only match everything after "]", grab the realName and then stop after it finds an "(" or "[".

If you want it to stop when it sees a `(` or `[`, but there does not *have* to be one or there might be more than one, then you need to be more picky about what you match leading up to that. `.+` will match any sequence of characters (and the second `+` in `(.+)+` is superfluous), and that can include `(` and `[` characters.  Something like this would work better:

```
]\s+([^[(]+)
```

There, the capture group cannot contain any `[` or `(` characters, so if there are any then the match will necessarily stop just before.

Comment: Same result as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51717113/5221149), except it captures the trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for this regex:

```
]\s+([^([\s]+(?:\s+[^([\s]+)*)
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vE4HID/1) for demo. Result is:

```
Shuu
Paradise ~★  Special Edition
Channel
X-Men!!
SPLASH 11
name1 | name2
Connect
~Hellverse~
Escape
```

*Explanation*

```
]\s+             Match lead-in, i.e. end-bracket and some spaces
(                Start capture group:
  [^([\s]+         Match anything except '(', '[', and spaces
  (?:              Start optional repeating group:
    \s+              Match one or more spaces
    [^([\s]+         Match anything except '(', '[', and spaces
  )*               End of repeating group
)                End of capture group
```

Comment: seems correct. Still have to check it. But why does it make two matching groups where the first one is " ]"?

Comment: @EsoMoa It will always capture the entire "match", as group 0. Any `(xxx)` capture groups are then numbered 1 and higher, in the order seen in the regex. In your code, you'd be calling `group(1)` to get the text in the capture group.